# Return Lucene field name when a query is matched

Tags: java, lucene

So I am using the MultiFieldQueryParser in Lucene 3.0.2, and I have given it multiple fields. I want to find out which field matched the query; I searched on here, and one user said there is absolutely no way to do this. Is this really true? If so, can anyone recommend a way around this or another system that would allow me to do this?

I can put the entire document in one field, "contents" for example, but I think this makes the problem even worse.

I want to query a database with, for example, Brad, and see whether the query came from a movie name, an actor's name, a director's name, etc. etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend the use of BooleanQuery with stnadard QueryParser:

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

FuzzyQuery field1Query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("field1", searchTerm), 0.3f, 1, 10);
FuzzyQuery field2Query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("field2", searchTerm), 0.3f, 1, 10);

booleanQuery.add(field1Query , BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
booleanQuery.add(field1Query , BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

This way you can perform search on exactly the fields you want and adjust it to produce fine tuned results. Assuming that is your ultimate goal.